# Parsing heredoc comments in BASH script

Tags: bash, syntax, coding-style

I have a collection of Bash scripts and would like to be able to parse them to extract their definitions.

If I form my descriptions within the scripts (ab)using heredocs for comment blocks as below, will this offer any benefits:

```
#!/bin/bash

DESCRIPTION = <<EOD

This nifty script does x, y and sometimes z

EOD

# rest of script...
```

over:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Description
# ==========
#
# This nifty script does x, y and sometimes z 

# rest of script...
```

ie, is there an easy way for me to pull a variable out of a Bash script or will I need to write a script to parse the file for the properly formatted description block from `# Description` to the next blank line?

**Update**

A lot of great answers for this. I chose the one which suits my use case and preference the best, but all are great examples of Bash commenting implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" = "DESCRIPTION" ] && cat <<EOD && exit

Hello, this is the ${1}

This nifty script does x, y and sometimes z
The nice thing is that linebreaks will be preserved.
This makes it a "useful"  'here document'

no problem with 'single' or "double" quotes
nothing matters much except variables

EOD


rest of script...
```

works great :-)

Answer (score 5):

There's no practical difference in terms of difficulty of extracting the information. The comments have a mild benefit of not being executable, so there's a marginal performance benefit to not creating the `$DESCRIPTION` variable, but you'd be hard pressed to measure it.

Of course, there's the additional issue that the syntax shown for the heredoc isn't valid shell. You'd need to think in terms of:

```
cat >/dev/null <<EOD
...
EOD
```

or perhaps (but perhaps not — unless you want to use `$DESCRIPTION` in the script itself):

```
DESCRIPTION=$(cat <<EOD
...
EOD
)
```

or, perhaps better still:

```
: DESCRIPTION = <<EOD
...
EOD
```

The colon command is a no-op; it evaluates its arguments and succeeds.  I prefer this to either of the `cat` variants.  The `DESCRIPTION` and `=` arguments are noise words; you could omit either or both without affecting the script.  You would probably want to think about using quotes around the first `EOD` too:

```
: <<'EOD'
...$(cat this is not executed)...
EOD
```

Note that the `:` command and first `cat` alternatives do not initialize the shell variable `$DESCRIPTION`. If that's important, you're stuck with the command substitution `$(...)` version, noting that there are two lines marking the end of the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Let your description lines begin with a unique identifier, something like this:

(for example we take the characters: #> )

```
#!/bin/bash

#> This is a description header
#> 
#> This program will do z, y and X
#> because I want that

# this is normal comment

.... rest of program 
or some other stuff
```

To get your description:

```
grep "^#>" myscript.sh
```

will result in:

```
#> This is a description header
#> 
#> This program will do z, y and X
#> because I want that
```

This is way easier than trying to get:

1. a variable out of a document 
   (which can only be done by partly sourcing it....which is another can of worms.)
2. Trying to retrive the part between (EOD) markers
3. Trying to heuristically determine which is comment or which is description.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having a variable that contains a description is very interesting.

The best way to retreive it from the program is to have the program print it for you.
Don't work with anything other than just single or double quotes because that is the only way to incorporate linebreaks in your variable.
We can also bypass the need for a variable by echoing the string directly.

You could have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#---------------------------------
[ "$1" = "DESCRIPTION" ] && echo '

Hello,

This nifty script does x, y and sometimes z
The nice thing is that linebreaks will be preserved.
This makes it as useful as a here document

you can choose between single or double quotes

' && exit
#---------------------------------

rest of script...
```

It does not look very pretty (though not bad either) but retreiving the description is extremely simple and without extra tools:

```
scriptname.sh DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: I really like how this needs no extra tooling to grab the description from CLI. Is there any way to tweak it to ignore single quotes within the description text without worrying about formatting?

Comment: Yes, if you use double quotes as begin and end markers, you can use single quotes in the text (and vice versa).

Comment: There is also another way. I will post that as another answer.